# webpack browser console message: WDS Disconnected

Tags: firefox, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This problem only happens in firefox.

I set up a minimal project with webpack and I keep receiving an error in Firefox console

**[WDS] Disconnected!**

Although I searched it online and there are many proposed solutions, unfortunately none of them applied to me. I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` and none of these tricks worked. I updated  `npm`. It didn't work either.

```
$ tree
.
├── aaa.js
├── aaa.png
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

File contents:

**aaa.js**

```
(empty)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './aaa.js',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8080,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      favicon:  "aaa.png"
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: I see similar error in other projects too such as https://github.com/rwieruch/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup

Comment: do you still get this issue if you don't use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` (e.g. hard code the script tag)? The only path forward in solving this issue for me was to strip my dependencies bare and try turning each one on slowly. Ultimately for my *very specific situation*, there was some contention between `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and [another framework I was using](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler).